# How to remove the duplicates values from only one element of the dictionary at a time?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, defaultdict

In this given dictionary `defaultdict(dict)` type data:

```
{726: {'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0}, 'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'chr': [2, 2, 2]}, 128: {'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'chr': [3, 3, 3]}}
```

the numeric value `726` and `128` are the keys and are unique. The other elements are the values tagged with `unique identifier` and are also unique.

I want to remove the duplicates only from the `list values` in `chr` **without affecting the data or order of the values** in any other parts of the dictionary.

How may I accomplish that?

Thanks,

Comment: so you want `'chr': 3` or `'chr': [3]`? Will all elements of `chr` be the same or is it possible to have other values?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @TemporalWolf: I think `'chr': '2'` is good. But, would it make any difference on downstream analyses when I do `for k in given_dict: `. Also, the values inside the `chr` are unique. But, could you propose a solution that might work to reduce it to unique values if there are duplicates. Just for my knowledge.

Comment: Do you care about the order of what's in `chr`? e.g. if you had `'chr': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]` would you want `[2, 1, 3]`? Or is any order fine?

Comment: Order needs to be strictly conserved. so, `[2, 1, 3]`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  `d` is your dictionary, you can simply do :

```
for k in d: d[k]['chr']=d[k]['chr'][0]
```

assuming unique value in chr.

If multiple values exists,

```
for k in d: 
 l=d[k]['chr']+[None]
 d[k]['chr']=[x for (i,x) in enumerate(l[:-1]) if l[i]!=l[i+1]]
```

will make the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested dict comprehension and convert the list to `set` in order to get a unique set of items. Since all them items within `chr`'s value are the same the set will generate 1 item and thus the order doesn't matter in this case. Otherwise you can use `OrderedDict.fromkeys()` to get a unique set of your items by preserving the order.

```
In [4]: {k: {k2: set(v2) if k2=='chr' else v2 for k2, v2 in v.items()} for k, v in d.items()}
Out[4]: 
{128: {'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'chr': {3}},
 726: {'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'chr': {2}}}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation so I can be more independent while progressing through my work. Thanks much though !

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason this method didn't work as it should. I am getting the nested dictionary like `{2}` instead of `'2'` or '[2]`. I hope its not going to create any problem while running `for k in given_dict: ...`. Thanks much though !

Comment: @everestial007 `{2}` is not a dictionary its a set and sets are iterable object, that said you can iterate over it using a for loop. But if you want  the object `2` not in any iterable you should probably use a simple loop instead of comprehension and handle all the occasions manually.

Comment: @nir0s Yeah. Actually that's the problem of abstraction, (if you thin of it that way ;))

Comment: @Kasramvd oh obviously. I didn't intend to imply that it's avoidable. I just got to a point in which I was writing some complex dict comprehensions and couldn't read them myself :)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is iterate through the unique keys and for each unique key choose the 'chr' key and transform its value to a set (which can only have unique values).

```
for lists in YOUR_DICT.values():
    lists['chr'] = list(set(lists['chr']))
print(YOUR_DICT)
# {'726': {'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'chr': [2]}, 
#  '128': {'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'chr': [3]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve the order of the lists:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a={726: {'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'chr': [2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3 ]}, 128: {'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'chr': [3, 3,3]}}
b=copy.deepcopy(a)
for key in b:
    a[key]['chr']=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(b[key]['chr']))
```

The original order of the top level keys in a will be lost the moment when a is created. If you want a to have 726 first you need to create it as OrderedDict from beginning.